# how to resolve Error: Cannot find module './vendor/parse'

Tags: php, node.js, npm, webpack, sass

i use  npm install, npm i -g node-sass, npm install --save-dev  --unsafe-perm node-sass, npm install sass -g  for fix this error:
```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
throw err;
^

````
    Error: Cannot find module './vendor/parse'
    Require stack:
     - C:\xampp\htdocs\customer3\node_modules\parse-json\index.js
     - C:\xampp\htdocs\customer3\node_modules\load-json-file\index.js
     - C:\xampp\htdocs\customer3\node_modules\read-pkg\index.js
     - C:\xampp\htdocs\customer3\node_modules\read-pkg-up\index.js
     - C:\xampp\htdocs\customer3\node_modules\meow\index.js
     - C:\xampp\htdocs\customer3\node_modules\node-sass\bin\node-sass
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\xampp\htdocs\customer3\node_modules\parse-json\index.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19) {
    code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
   requireStack: [
      'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\customer3\\node_modules\\parse-json\\index.js',
      'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\customer3\\node_modules\\load-json-file\\index.js',
      'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\customer3\\node_modules\\read-pkg\\index.js',
      'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\customer3\\node_modules\\read-pkg-up\\index.js',
      'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\customer3\\node_modules\\meow\\index.js',
     'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\customer3\\node_modules\\node-sass\\bin\\node-sass'
    ]
   }
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! errno 1
   npm ERR! customer3@1.0.0 compile:sass: `node-sass template/front/tem_master/sass/main.scss 
   template/front/tem_master/css/style.css -w`       
   npm ERR! Exit status 1
   npm ERR!
   npm ERR! Failed at the customer3@1.0.0 compile:sass script.
   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   npm ERR!     C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-01T05_17_03_551Z-debug.log

   npm run compile:sass not work.
```
````